# Validate Video View appium (java) android

Tags: android, testing, automation, appium, android-videoview

I am automating android app using Appium (java).
I have `android.widget.VideoView` on the page and using `verifyElementByClass` , I can check whether the Video View exists on that page.
Now I need to check if it is playing any video or not? 
How to do that?

Comment: could you share a screenshot, though considering a normal video player I believe presence of something like a `pause_button` on your screen shall be depicting that

Comment: yes @nullpointer the pause button seekbar etc are coming as overlay but UIAutomator is unable to capture it as it stays for very less time

Comment: ok, got it. could you try to touchscreen coordinate and then validate the buttons.

Comment: the other way I would have suggested to properly validate if the video is actually getting played is the comparison of screenshots at different timestamps using OCR which is yet not implemented in Appium.

Comment: if your problem is resolved, could you please select mark the answer to this.

Comment: Any updates here @AnswerDroid? Please mark an answer or update accordingly,

Answer (score 3):

Asserting the elements `pause_button` , `seekbar` etc. depicts that the video is being played. According to the comment :

> the pause button seekbar etc are coming as overlay but UIAutomator is
>   unable to capture it as it stays for very less time

One way to perform the action is to tap on the `android.widget.VideoView` and then `Assert` the presence of the elements so that the overlay is present while you are asserting.

---

Other way I would have suggested to properly validate if the video is actually getting played is the comparison of screenshots at different timestamps using OCR which is yet not implemented in Appium. These might be of help for [Screenshots](https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-can-we-identify-any-image-on-mobile-app-using-appium/3581/14) and [OCR-Apppium](http://sauceio.com/index.php/2014/06/live-panel-mobile-testing-with-appium-recap/).

Comment: @AnswerDroid : what problem does persists could you Edit the question and add to it.